# Angular detect left mouse click and right mouse click

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I've been trying to recreate Minesweeper using it. I've been successful in terms of detecting left clicks for revealing a tile and right clicks for flagging a tile, but I'm not sure how to detect both the left and right mouse keys being pressed for revealing larger areas. Is there a way to detect that?

Comment: Hi Yiwen, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you include code snippets of your code that does the detection of left clicks/right clicks etc, so that other contributors can assist you in your question? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

import `HostListener`

`import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";`

On right click event, use `contextmenu` event.

```
@HostListener("contextmenu", ["$event"])
   onRightClick(event) {
      //your code here
   }
```

On left click event, use `click` event.

```
@HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick() {
    //code here
  }
```

for both clicks add `timeout` to each right and left click event since most case both clicks can't be trigger at same time one click will be always ahead of the other and perform if there is proceeding clicks. in my working code the right click still triggers on both click. I don't know if this because of the `preventdefault` but you can add another condition if both click is perform then you can already perform the right click.

see working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yzh4wh

```
right_clickOnly: boolean = true;
left_clickOnly: boolean = true; 

@HostListener("contextmenu", ["$event"])
  onRightClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.right_clickOnly = false;
    if (!this.left_clickOnly) {
      this.performBothClick();
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.right_clickOnly = true;
        this.right_click += 1;
      }, 300);
      // this.right_clickOnly = false;

    }
  }

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick() {
    this.left_clickOnly = false;

    if (!this.right_clickOnly) {
      this.performBothClick();
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.left_clickOnly = true;
        this.left_click += 1;
      }, 300);
      // this.left_clickOnly = false;

    }
  }

  performBothClick() {
    this.both_click +=1;
    this.right_clickOnly = true;
    this.left_clickOnly = true;
  
  }
```

Comment: I was able to get left click and right click working, but I'm not sure how to detect when both are pressed at the same time?

Comment: see my edit. I already added both click fucntion